# How do I make nested drop down menus in HTML?

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu

I am working on my school's website, and I have already figured out how to make single drop downs. Here is the code for one menu item.

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #0a0a2a;
  font-family: Arial;
  border: 3px solid #C5B358;
  margin-left: -75px;
  margin-right: -75px;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  background-color: #0a0a2a;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #C5B358;
  padding-top: 9px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #0a0a2a;
  min-width: 140px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #C5B358;
  color: #0a0a2a;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form action="index.html">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">HOME </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">

    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<!--Modular code begins here-->

<form action="aboutus.html">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">ABOUT US 
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Calendar 2017-2018</a>
      <a href="#">Inclement Weather Information</a>
      <a href="#">Directions to Tri-County</a>
      <a href="#">2016 Report Card</a>
      <a href="#">District Information</a>
      <a href="#">Business Office</a>
      <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      <a href="#">Public Records</a>
      <a href="#">School Committee</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

This works just fine, but some of the menu options, in this case "Business Office", have a submenu that needs to be added. Ideally, this would be a hover drop down that appears to the right of the drop down menu.

However, I can not figure out how this should work, and nothing on the internet seems to answer my question fully. So, I decided to consult trusty old Stack Overflow.

I tried adding the following code to my HTML, making new classes in the CSS with the same properties as the original drop down menu. It did not work.

```
<div class="sub-dropdown">
    <button class="sub-dropbtn"> District Information</button>
    <div class="sub-dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">School Committee</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

If anybody can help me figure out where I went wrong, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to do from stratch rethinking about how, i can't start something that help you with this cos that will no been responsive. Why are you using FORM inside the menu :(. You want to show the best pratice as example ?

Comment: I am using FORM to get the dropdown to also link to a webpage if you click on it. I don't know how to do it otherwise.